# How can I import a model object file into my watch extension if it has a lot of dependencies

Tags: ios, watchkit, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, apple-watch

I am working on building a companion app to an existing iOS app that is quite large and has pieces that are somewhat archaic. There is a list in the iOS app that has items that are of type ClassA lets say. Persistence is handled by archiving these objects to disk and reading back out when needed.

I changed the location of the save to be in a shared container that the watch app can read, but the watch extension can't make sense of the list because it doesn't know about ClassA. Fair enough. I add ClassA.m to by Compile Sources in the target settings and then we have a ton of errors due to imports and dependencies associated with ClassA.

I start adding more and more classes and before long it is throwing errors in files all across the project that seemingly have nothing to do with ClassA.

So now I am wondering if this is all required for what I am trying to do. I just want to be able to read an archive of objects of type ClassA in my watch extension, do I need to import half of the iOS app into the watch extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your `ClassA` is a model class which stores some data and processes it. In this case I would recommend you to refactor your `ClassA` so it will have only properties and methods that don't depends on other classes and move all other methods to class extension (or several extensions if appropriate).
**Example:**
Before:

```
class DependentClass {
   func goodFunction(a: Int) -> Int{ return a * 5 }

   func dependantFunction(b: AnotherDependantClass) -> AnotherDependantClass2{ ... }
}
```

After:

```
class DependentClass {
   func goodFunction(a: Int) -> Int{ return a * 5 }
}

//In another file
extension DependentClass{
   func dependantFunction(b: AnotherDependantClass) -> AnotherDependantClass2{ ... }

}
```

**EDIT**
Example in Objective-C: 
Before:

```
//DependentClass.h
@class AnotherDependantClass;
@class AnotherDependantClass2;

@interface DependentClass : NSObject

-(int)goodFunction:(int)a;
-(AnotherDependantClass2 *)dependantFunction:(AnotherDependantClass *)a;

@end
```

After:

```
//DependentClass.h
@interface DependentClass : NSObject

-(int)goodFunction:(int)a;

@end

//DependentClass+Dependencies.h
@class AnotherDependantClass;
@class AnotherDependantClass2;

@interface DependentClass (Dependencies)

-(AnotherDependantClass2 *)dependantFunction:(AnotherDependantClass *)a;

@end
```

After that include your `DependentClass.m` in your watch extension and add `#import "DependentClass+Dependencies.h"` where appropriate. Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I like where this is headed. Many of the class's methods that have dependent parameter types are in the header. How would I refactor in such a case? Sorry, still using Objective-C.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks!